# CSS div not listening to my max-width attribute

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**EDIT:** I think my code is fine. It was just the skew that made it a bit stretched out haha. Sorry

I normally would say my CSS skills are above average but this is seriously making me rethink that...

```css
.our-work-container {
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    transform: skew(-12deg);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.our-work-container .header-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    height: 260px;
}

.our-work-container .header-section .brand-square {
    width: 350px;
    min-width: 350px;
    max-width: 350px;
    background: yellow;
}

.our-work-container .header-section .header-text {
    padding-left: 60px;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    transform: skew(12deg);
}

.our-work-container .header-section .header-text h1 { 
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 4em;
}

.our-work-container .header-section .header-text h2 {
    font-family: Lora,serif!important;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="our-work-container">
      <div class="header-section">
        <div class="brand-square"></div>
        <div class="header-text">
          <h1>Our Work</h1>
          <div class="brand-line-break"></div>
          <h2>Marketing is our passion, each project we take on is in collaboration with each of our team members, ensuring high quality marketing experiences.</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="projects"></div>
    </div>
```

The colors are placeholders but can you guys tell me the reasoning why my yellow square(.brand-square) isnt listening to the max width attributes. When I inspect the element, I don't see anything that is messing with the styles.

My guess would be somehow flexbox is altering those values but I cant seem to figure out what.

Would really appreciate the insight. Thank you!

Comment: Becuase a flex-child ignores `max-width` If you want a set size, use the flex properties available. `flex: 0 0 350px`. Basically, flex-grow` overrides `max-width`

Comment: Interesting... I never that. Will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: With the container's `flex-wrap` set to _nowrap_, flex will always make the combined width of children to add up to 100%. Use `flex-basis` to adjust widths on flex children.

Comment: @Paulie_D hm... I changed it to flex: 0 0 350px; and t still stretches to ~400px

Comment: @PeterHvD Hey Peter, the container already has flex-wrap set to nowrap. The flex-flow property combines direction and wrap into 1.

Comment: Not that I can see...are you sure the `transform` isn't throwing you off

Comment: What you are seeing is **visual only**...the size of the element does not actually change.

Comment: Yes, that's my point - if you have nowrap then it will try to make all widths add up to 100%

Answer (score -1):

just delete the `width:350px` inside 
`.our-work-container .header-section .brand-square` class

find the working fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/15xLs49j/2/

But as a advice, it is not a good practice to give static height as your content must be responsive and static values in css can ruin the responsiveness.

Comment: I need static values because of the other things ill be adding into the page right after i finish with this bug. I always make sure to make my sites responsive with media queries and whatnot so im not worried.

Comment: wooha, just a negative, but you must leave a comment before marking it negative, please mark the issue correctly.

Comment: Wasn't me if that's what you were inferring @Rnayak